# mongodb prefer one db rather then other in the same instance

Tags: mongodb

I have one mongod instance with some db's inside it.
I want to set that one of the db's will be more fast and stable, means that if there is lots of queries and work in one db it wont effect the more important db.

is this  possible?

thanks

Comment: Not clear what you are asking about. MongoDB reads and writes to a single instance by preference, and even in a replica set you really should always be reading from the primary unless you really know what you are doing and what that really means. It does not sound like you have that level of understanding here.

Comment: I'm not asking about different servers ' Im talking about a situation you created 2 db's in one instance(doesn't matter if its a rs or stand alone) and I want to configure it so if there is a lot of workload on both db's I want one of them to get  more of the computer resources because I prefer one to work faster than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.
You can't prioritize the queries per db.